# Not able to login into facebook from my app from other android devices except mine

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions, facebook-login

I have looked up on google,stackoverflow,whole internet...But nothing seems to solve this problem. I think I am missing some minute detail which will fix this issue. Below is the desciption :

I have integrated FB login in my android app. It works fine on my device but when ran on other devices, when clicked on login, it asks for permission and when given, it goes back to Login state...It means session is not getting opened on other devices..I have also used below code to generate hash key :

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "MY_PACKAGE_NAME", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) { 
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
}
```

I have also placed hash key on fb page of the app using my keystore with which I am exporting the app(final one) and using correct password to generate hash key by below method (Note i am using Windows 7):

keytool -list-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

Ofcourse I used my releasekey and the final keystore in the above command. It asked for password and I gave correct one. So I guess, hash key generated was correct. If used -exportcert instead of -list , it shows "invalid type -exportcert" .

I have added 4 key hashes till now on fb page. Sandbox mode is off.

I have been banging my head with this issue since past 6 days.I think there is some problem with hash key causing other users not letting open a fb session from app. Kindly someone help if u had faced similar problem or possible solution/approach will also help.

Appreciate your time and valuable comments.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you manage to find a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: almost the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215610/facebook-login-in-andorid-with-different-devices

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -list-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I see you're using your debug key, try to export your application from eclipse assistant and then create your own keystore. Once you have it created run again the previous command changing the name of key and the path of your keystore, then put the hash key on facebook page and install the exported .apk in other devices.

The .apk generated from the "run" option are signed with your debug key, while the exported with export assistant is signed with your personal key.

Comment: Hi Constantino, As I have mentioned below keytool command "Ofcourse I used my releasekey and the final keystore in the above command". So I have used the keystore and key I have created by while taking export from eclipse and not used the debug keystore and debug key. I had put that hash key in fb page and then installed exported .apk on other devices...but still same problem persists :(

Comment: @user2499971 Strange error, have you tried to connect those devices via USB and check the output logs?Guide for USB debugging:  
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html  
Also, keep in mind that if the installed native facebook app in the device is old enough, maybe it can't have implemented yet the actual login process. Try to update it

Comment: Have you put the tag **android:noHistory="true"** in your manifest file? Try to delete it

Comment: In the logs, it displays nothing...I have checked .... I have not put android:noHistory tag in my manifest file.